# XCode won't let me open any folders. Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I'm making a reactJS app with cordova and firebase and I've been using VScode throughout the whole process. This month I'm looking to publish my very first app to the app store but in order to do that I need to use XCode. For some reason XCode is being very strange. It lets me clone my repository from github and save it to my desktop, but when I try to open it, i get prompted with an error saying "xcode failed to open (Users/ethan/Desktop/react-website-xCode").

I suspect this may have something to do with my environment variables or something but i'm honestly clueless. Any idea why this is happening?

Some background info:

Im running my OS, Xcode and my project from my 2TB seagate drive,

I also have the latest version of IOS installed as-well as the latest version of XCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using reactJS and you have at least one debug build, you have to open the `.xworkspace` folder of your project on Xcode. That file is located on the 'ios' folder of your project.

Comment: I literally just found the answer to this question not even 5 minutes ago but i'll still give you the check and the upvote for helping me out, and so that other people who view this in future can find the answer. For absolute clarity. You need to navigate to the following file.                                                     Platforms/IOS/<Your-App-Name>. xcworkspace